# Javascript to add values of a table

Tags: javascript

my HTML code looks like this

```
<TR Row="1" CLASS="ThemeAlignCenter">
                <TD id="wrdActive_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                    CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblactive_Row1">6</SPAN></TD>

... more rows
```

I want to put a javascript at the end of the page to add all of the the values of lblactive_row1 when ever it appears in the page (in this example the number 6)

**Edit: more source**

```
    <TABLE style="" border="0" CLASS="rdThemeDataTable" id="dtWardData"
                cellspacing="0">
                <COL id="wrdActive"></COL>
                <COL id="wrdOccupied"></COL>
                <TR Row="1" CLASS="ThemeAlignCenter">
                    <TD id="wrdActive_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblactive_Row1">4</SPAN></TD>
                    <TD id="wrdOccupied_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblOccupied_Row1">4</SPAN></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>

   <TABLE style="" border="0" CLASS="rdThemeDataTable" id="dtWardData"
                cellspacing="0">
                <COL id="wrdActive"></COL>
                <COL id="wrdOccupied"></COL>

                    <TD id="wrdActive_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblactive_Row1">6</SPAN></TD>
                    <TD id="wrdOccupied_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblOccupied_Row1">2</SPAN></TD>

                </TR>
            </TABLE>

    Repeat...
```

it goes on like that for another 10 or so tables, all in the same source. editting the html is out of the question because its generated by a third party tool. all i can is add a little script at the end

Comment: where to add the values?

Comment: Do the other SPANs have ids like 'lblactive_Row2', 'lblactive_Row3'?

Comment: @martjin. No all of them are called lblactive_row1

Comment: @awias add the values together

Comment: Just as a small heads up, you shouldn't be using uppercase HTML tags anymore or at least don't mix upper, lower and mixed case. Be consistent. It helps yourself out in the end!

Comment: @gnur its automatically generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on whether you're using jQuery or not, you might have to modify your HTML to make it easier to pick out the elements you need.

With jQuery you should be able to do something like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('table tr.ThemeAlignCenter > td.rdThemeDataTableCell > span').each(function(i) {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Without jQuery, assuming your <table> has an id of *data*, something along these lines should help:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('data');
var cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, limit = cells.length; i < limit; i++) {
    var td = cells[i];
    if (td.className === 'rdThemeDataTableCell') {
        var elem = td.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        total += parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: refactored the code so it can be applied to each table (should hopefully work if the table id attributes can't be amended and have to remain identical):

```
function sumTable(tbl) {
    var cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, limit = cells.length; i < limit; i++) {
        var td = cells[i];
        if (td.className === 'rdThemeDataTableCell') {
            var elem = td.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            total += parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
        }
    }

    return total;
}

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var results = [];
for (var i = 0, limit = tables.length; i < limit; i++) {
    var total = sumTable(tables[i]);
    results.push(total);
}
```

Comment: im trying this but it doesnt work. i dont even get an exmpty alert

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var tbl = document.getElementById('dtWardData');
 var cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName('wrdActive_Row1');

 var total = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var td = cells[i];
    if (td.className == 'rdThemeDataTableCell') {
        var elem = td.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        total += parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
    }
 alert(total);
 
}
</script>

all the cells have the same name and theyre repeated all over the page because ive got 3 pages nested inside eachother

Comment: Do all your tables get output with the same HTML id? If so, I'm wondering whether that might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
function totalRows() {
    var total = 0;
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
        if(spans[i].getAttribute('id') === 'lblactive_Row1') {
            total += parseInt( spans[i].innerHTML, 10);
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

attach totalRows() to an eventHandler

Comment: You forgot to specify the radix in the `parseInt` function call.  `parseInt('010')` will return 8, not 10; `parseInt('010', 10)` will return 10. http://nicolaasmatthijs.blogspot.com/2009/05/missing-radix-parameter.html

Comment: no they lblactive does not icrement. theyre all called lblactive_Row1

Comment: @user521180 Removed increment id in id attribute. @Martjin good catch on the parseInt, I added this too.